# Genre of music by the band "Los Deltonos"?

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

I'm looking for similar music to the Spanish band "Los Deltonos."  What genre is this band's music, and what are other songs in that same genre?

(Singing in Spanish would be a plus, but other languages are fine.)

Song sample of "Los Deltonos" - [Horizonte Eléctrico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwBO3P7GhGY)

Comment: Hi @AndrésBiarge, welcome to the site!  Straight recommendation questions are discouraged here, so I converted your question to a genre-identification question.  You should still get the same kind of answers (if there is someone who knows the genre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was in English I would describe this particular song as mainstream indie-pop, pop-rock or power-pop with a late 90s or early 2000s feel.  Compare the following:

Third Eye Blind - [Semi Charmed Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tC1NR7AL_9s)  (1997)
Fountains of Wayne - [Hey Julie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZxJNZMyn-4) (2003)
Weezer - [Island in the Sun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVHUjzZZGQ4) (2001)
Phantom Planet - [California](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq-S8CIU7VA) (2002)

Their Wikipedia page describes them as having a strong blues influence, which isn't evident in this song, but is in some of the [other tracks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQM2GQUnRD4) I heard.  It's a more pop version of the blues then you usually hear in America --the closest thing in English is probably early "British invasion" music like [Eric Clapton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKAYGVIkbok) or the [Yardbirds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU5zqidlxMQ).

You might try searching power-pop, indie pop, or pop-blues on Spanish language search engines or resources for Spanish language bands with this sound.